# How does friction facilitate charge redistribution?

Tags: electrostatics, friction

We know that when Amber is rubbed with wool, the surfaces that are in contact, taken together, have the charges redistributed in accordance with the Law of Conservation of Charge. How does friction facilitate this redistribution?

Answer (score 1):

### Friction and Triboelectric Charging

- Commonly known as [Static Electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity), the charge redistribution effect of the [triboelectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) pair of wool and amber is primarily due to the difference in electron affinities of the amber and wool molecules.

  - Mere contact between two surfaces with dissimilar charge affinity is sufficient to produce triboelectric charge accumulation.  Rubbing/Friction is *not* necessary to redistribute electrons.
  - A maximum charge redistribution is attained with total/full/complete surface to surface contact and separation.
  - Less charge accumulates with less surface contact.  Microscopic surface irregularities, called [asperities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperity_(materials_science)), prevent contact in the deep valley/crevices between peaks where contact is made.
- Factors influencing Charge Redistribution:

  - 1) Increased *[electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity) differential* (alternatively measured as the *[work function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function) differential*) between the pairs in the Triboelectric Series increases charge redistribution.
  - 2) Increased *compressive pressure* results in increased charge redistribution, because flattening atomic-level surface irregularities produces increased surface area contact.
  - 3) Increased *rate of separation* (i.e., pulling surfaces apart more rapidly) produces an increase in charge redistribution.
  - 4) Increased *temperature* changes the charge distribution of the electrons within the molecule, resulting in a changed electronegativity between surface pairs.
  - 5) Increased *humidity* neutralizes charge redistribution, as water molecules provide a medium which transports and equalizes the charge on the oppositely charged surfaces.

**Friction Effect #1: Surface Area, Pressure and Adhesion**

- Def: [*Asperities*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperity_(materials_science)): microscopic to atom-level surface irregularities.
- Def: *Moderate Pressure*: A contact pressure which would flatten some asperities but not result in full surface to surface contact.
- Def: *[Adhesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhesion)*: The binding force between molecules on opposing surfaces. Adhesion encompasses a broad range of bonding methods to bind surfaces together.
- In the context of friction between two dissimilar materials, where their method of bonding is a combination a mixture of covalent and ionic, a fitting name for this mixture is polar covalent.  The bond of adhesion include elements of: 1) [covalent bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond) (equally shared electrons - with the attraction between atoms produced by the mutual nucleus attraction to the shared electrons, and 2) [ionic bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_bonding) (fully appropriated orbitals to create a full shell, resulting in an attraction between atoms due to their opposite charge).

  - Adhesion between surface molecules results in a bond distance which is an equilibrium position between repulsion and attraction, which is the point of energy minimization.  Moving the pair away from equilibrium bond length requires force and energy. The energy supplied in distension will be stored in the bond.
  - Separating such bonded molecules on opposite surfaces results in stretching and ultimately overcoming the force exerted by these polar-covalent bonds.  The force applied requires energy expenditure as Work to stretch and break the bonds between molecules.  The energy applied in stretching the bond is carried by the captured electron to the atom or molecule with the greatest electronegative attraction (which corresponds to the molecular location with the deepest energy well).
  - The experience of friction as a force resisting movement arises from fact that adhesive bonds resist any movement away from equilibrium. The work done in producing movement against the force of friction is applied to the captured electron and is eventually dissipated as heat/thermal energy.
- [Friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction) (movement between surfaces with pressure) provides the opportunity for more contact between irregular surfaces. At the atomic level, asperities do not allow a full molecule to molecule contact between two surfaces at modest pressures.  But, movement with pressure (rubbing) provides the opportunity for surface areas to touch which have not yet made contact (e.g., such as the penetration of peaks into the valleys of opposing asperities).

**Conversion of Work against Friction into Thermal Energy**

- The two factors producing heat due to friction are:

  - A) Adhesion: Orbital activation resulting from stretching and breaking the bonds of molecular adhesion formed between surfaces during movement.
  - B) Lateral Deformation: Elastic and inelastic deformation of asperities due to lateral force displacement, cause distended bonds and then reformation. The electrons involved in compression and distension retain the energy of the deformation/restoration process as activated electrons.
- 1) *Adhesion* (as described above) is the bonding force between surface molecules. Force and input of energy is required to stretch and break those bonds.  Separation of surfaces results in the breakage of the polar covalent bonds.  Upon separation, the previously shared electron associates with the more electronegative molecule - hence charge redistribution.  And, after capture the energy supplied to stretch and break the adhesive bonds is held in the activated orbitals.

  - This excess orbital energy is capable of collision and transfer to another electron or atom as numerous types of atomic-level motion. The large numbers and random orientations of these captured and activated electron orbitals make it obvious that we may categorize this energy as a form of thermal energy on the atomic scale.
  - In summary, the conversion of Work=$F \Delta x$ against friction, results in the increased kinetic energy of electron orbital activation, which in turn may produce various manifestations of thermal energy such as rotation, translation, and atom/molecule and lattice vibration.  Such is the sequence of energy flow from macroscopic work and kinetic energy to the disordered kinetic energy of atom-level thermal energy and the energy held in electric fields.
- 2) *Interdigitation and lateral collisions* result from microscopic surface irregularities which resist sliding past each other.

  - On a macro scale, this is like sliding two pieces of knobby rubber mats over each other. The knobs may interdigitate and make contact on the sides of their knobs and therefore resist sliding past each other. As a result, sliding the mats over each other requires bending the rubber knobs and exerting sufficient force to produce the required deformation to slip past.
  - On a microscopic scale, asperities sliding past each other will undergo either elastic (bending and reforming) or inelastic deformation (breakage).  This deformation requires force, which (in addition to the force of adhesion) we feel as the resistance of *kinetic friction* when we slide/rub/move one surface over another.
  - In the case of elastic deformation, the molecules are pushed laterally, and when the peaks have passed over each other, the deformed bonds and atoms recoil back to their original position and bond length. The force applied over the distance of the deformation puts energy into the bond. That energy is still in the electron orbital after the bond length and atomic positions have reformed. The activated orbital eventually dissipates that energy as various types of motion on the atomic scale and is referred to as thermal energy. The thermal motions of the activated electron give it the additional mobility which allow it to move to another position in the molecule with more electronegative attraction and manifest the pyroelectric effect.

**Friction Effect #2: Temperature and the Pyroelectric Effect on Charge Redistribution**

- Increased temperature produces an electrical polarization of some molecules - typically crystals.  To rationalize this phenomenon, consider that energy is conserved, and in this context, energy is partitioned into three types: electrical, thermal, and kinetic energy.

  - (Note that electrical energy is held in a field between electrical charges of opposite polarity, hence it is a type of potential energy.  And, that both macroscopic kinetic energy and microscopic thermal energy are types of kinetic energy.)
  - When heat is added to a pyroelectric material, the electrons constituting its molecules mobilize and reposition themselves and change their electrical gradient based upon the new topology of the electron concentration on the molecule.
  - In the case of friction, the energy source for producing the pyroelectric effect is the work done to move the surfaces against resistance.  Force is applied, an increment of movement stretches bonds, storing potential energy in the bond distension.  Upon bond breakage, that field energy is converted to the kinetic energy of the activated/higher-orbital radius electron, which is a type of thermal energy.  Thus, kinetic energy is converted into thermal energy through adhesive bond breakage and elastic deformation.  The increased thermal energy imparted to the electrons frees them to relocate within the molecule to occupy volumes on the molecular topology with greater electronegative attraction.
  - The changed location of electron probability produces a changed topology of the electrical gradient (points of high and low electron concentration, and hence the direction and strength of the electrical gradient).
  - This changed electrical potential gradient may change the relative affinities of the electrons to the molecules on the other surface.  This may result in a change in the charge redistribution between the two materials.
  - Thus, heating by friction (or other by other thermal energy influx) may result in a changed relative electronegativity and a change in the redistribution of electrons with triboelectric charging.
  - For example: if amber or wool exhibit a pyroelectric redistribution of electrons, which changes their relative electronegativity, when friction heats the amber and wool their charge redistribution will change.